# Is it possible to encapsulate P5 into a global variable like JQuery does with $

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I was wondering if it's possible to remove the entire P5(or whatever other frame work/lib) from the global variable
and put it inside one single global variable without actually edit the P5.JS project it's self.

Just like JQuery does with the $ symbol. So you can actually declare variables named point, or mouseX that are P5 variable and will conflict with your variable.

So for example

```
window.P5 = (some way to get the all instance form the P5);
let point = {myPont:..., props....};
let canvasPoint = P5.point(...);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure. Use [instance mode](https://github.com/processing/p5.js/wiki/Global-and-instance-mode).

```
var s = function( sketch ) {

  var x = 100; 
  var y = 100;

  sketch.setup = function() {
    sketch.createCanvas(200, 200);
  };

  sketch.draw = function() {
    sketch.background(0);
    sketch.fill(255);
    sketch.rect(x,y,50,50);
  };
};

var myp5 = new p5(s);
```

Comment: Now every thing need the sketch variable first, which was exactly what I was looking for, I can have my object called point with no conflict with P5 function point(x, y). thanks, I didn't saw that part of the documentation. Very well pointed out.